# Panda stacking columns to rows with respect to some other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry my question is not really clear from the title but what I'm trying to do is exactly this
with pandas
from this:

```
col1  col2   col3   col 4
A     D      G       X
B     E      H       Y
C     F      I       Z
```

to this

```
col   col 4
A   X
B   Y
C   Z
D   X
E   Y
F   Z
G   X
H   Y
I   Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.melt(id_vars='col4', value_vars=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).drop(columns='variable')
```

Output:

```
    col value
0   X   A
1   Y   B
2   Z   C
3   X   D
4   Y   E
5   Z   F
6   X   G
7   Y   H
8   Z   I
```

Comment: is it possible to add another id_vars column ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just give a python list of columns you want them to be as `id_vars`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) as follows:

```
df.melt(id_vars='col4', value_name='col').drop('variable', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  col4 col
0    X   A
1    Y   B
2    Z   C
3    X   D
4    Y   E
5    Z   F
6    X   G
7    Y   H
8    Z   I
```

Answer (score 0):

out_df = pd.DataFrame()
out_df['col'] = df['col1'].tolist() + df['col2'].tolist() + df['col3'].tolist()

out_df['col 4'] = df['col 4'].tolist() * 3